# HTML rich formatting to MediaWiki markup

Tags: html, mediawiki, wiki, converters

Is an (online) HTML rich text editor to (media)Wiki markup does (or could) exist?

Note: please, before downvoting my question, tell me how to improve it.

If I want to convert rich format text (via cut & paste) to Wiki markup, should I go though first, a rich text editor -> to -> HTML,
And after that cut & paste the HTML code to a MediaWiki converter?

To contextualize my question, as it's often asked:
For instance, I've found the site [htmleditor.io](https://htmleditor.io), where I can paste text, and it keeps the formatting, and convert it automatically in HTML code.

I want to use this code in a private MediaWiki wiki, (even if I have to make some corrections), and to automate the process the more possible, with simple code.

Is it something that is feasable?

Answer (score 0):

MediaWiki's own WYSIWYG editor, [VisualEditor](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/VisualEditor), is able to handle HTML cut&paste to some extent.

(I note this is a very different problem from htmleditor.io where you are basically asking the editor to convert HTML to HTML, which as you might guess is not very hard.)

Comment: So, to be sure it answers my question: could I be able to cut & paste rich format text, and to have converti it to wiki markup?

Comment: Some conversion would happen, yes. It's not super sophisticated (supporting copy&paste from arbitrary web pages wasn't a major goal; supporting it from another wiki article or editor window was), but if you are looking for something basic, to handle things like bold text and bullet points, it will do that.

Comment: Thank you for all your precious help; I will activate this extension on my wiki, and give it a try. In the meanwhile, is there somewhere I can try or use online this editor, for instance pretending to edit a wiki page without confirming?

Comment: Wikipedia, I suppose? :)

Comment: Tested, and it doesn't render a rich format text like htmleditor, it makes a simple paste.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what's the implied difference. It's a WYSIWYG editor, which renders the edited article as it would look after saving (which includes discarding or plaintextifying some pasted content that could not be represented in wikitext).

Comment: I'm looking for a way to keep the formatting, as htmleditor does.

Comment: Not always, I mean keeping = pasting -> and pasting the formatting too.A WYSIWYG is more often used rather to create rich format than to paste it from another source.